# Creating and using LuceneAnalysisDefinitionProvider with Hibernate Search

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

When you search Stackoverflow or the Internet for `LuceneAnalysisDefinitionProvider`, you'll find hundreds of pages, each of them having the same code copied from another page without any decent explanation or further examples of usage.

So I tried to do it by myself and failed. Here is my code:

```
public class CustomLuceneAnalysisDefinitionProvider
        implements LuceneAnalysisDefinitionProvider {

  @Override
  public void register(final LuceneAnalysisDefinitionRegistryBuilder builder) {
    builder
      .analyzer("customAnalyzer")
        .tokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
        .charFilter(MappingCharFilterFactory.class)
          .param("mapping",
            "org/hibernate/search/test/analyzer/mapping-chars.properties")
        .tokenFilter(ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class)
        .tokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
        .tokenFilter(StopFilterFactory.class)
          // WRONG! It's not "mapping"!
//        .param("mapping",
//          "org/hibernate/search/test/analyzer/stoplist.properties")
          .param("words",
            "classpath:/stoplist.properties")
          .param("ignoreCase", "true");
  }

}
```

Now we have `CustomLuceneAnalysisDefinitionProvider` and what's next?

1. Where to put and how to address `mapping-chars.properties` when adding it as a `parameter` to `MappingCharFilterFactory`?
2. What is the contents of `mapping-chars.properties` and how to create mine of modify existing?
3. Where to put `stoplist.properties` and how to address it when adding as `mapping` parameter to `StopFilterFactory`?
4. How to add previously defined `customAnalyzer` to single `@Field` mentioned below?

```
@Field(
    index = Index.YES,
    analyze = Analyze.YES,
    store = Store.NO,
    bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = LocalizedFieldBridge.class)
)
private LocalizedField description;
```

On some pages I found option to put this definition into application.properties:

```
hibernate.search.lucene.analysis_definition_provider = com.thevegcat.app.search.CustomAnalysisDefinitionProvider
```

But I don't want to replace original analyzer, I just want to use custom analyzer for few specific properties.

---

**EDIT#1**

Looking into `org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilterFactory` line 86, one can notice it takes `words` as a key, not `mapping`.

---

**EDIT#2**

If you put your stop words file in src/main/resources, then you have to address it:

```
.param("words", "classpath:/stoplist.properties")
```

Answer (score 1):

> you'll find hundreds of pages, each of them having the same code copied from another page without any decent explanation or further examples of usage.

Hibernate Search 5 had its problems, one of which was lack of documentation in some areas. Now that it's in maintenance mode, those problems are unlikely to get addressed.

There is *some* documentation for that feature in the Hibernate Search 5 documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-analyzer-definition

You'll get [better documentation of that feature](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-lucene-analysis) by migrating to Hibernate Search 6+.

That being said, most of your questions related to Lucene features, so you probably won't find answers in Hibernate Search's documentation. You could find them in Lucene's documentation. How to find such documentation is explained in the Hibernate Search 6 documentation:

> To know more about the behavior of these character filters, tokenizers and token filters, either browse the [Lucene Javadoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_1/core/) or read the corresponding section on the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters) (you don’t need Solr to use these analyzers, it’s just that there is no documentation page for Lucene proper).

---

> Where to put and how to address mapping-chars.properties when adding it as a parameter to MappingCharFilterFactory?

In your classpath.

> What is the contents of mapping-chars.properties and how to create mine of modify existing?

That's the kind of things that Lucene doesn't document, at least not clearly. Solr's documentation is better: https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.MappingCharFilterFactory

> Where to put stoplist.properties and how to address it when adding as mapping parameter to StopFilterFactory?

Put it in the classpath, and pass the path to that file from the root of your classpath.

> How to add previously defined customAnalyzer to single @Field mentioned below?

Well *that* is documented, at least: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_referencing_named_analyzers

```
@Field(analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "customAnalyzer"))
```

> On some pages I found option to put this definition into application.properties:
>
> ```
> hibernate.search.lucene.analysis_definition_provider = com.thevegcat.app.search.CustomAnalysisDefinitionProvider
> ```
>
> But I don't want to replace original analyzer, I just want to use custom analyzer for few specific properties.

You won't replace an "analyzer", you will register an analysis definition provider. Which will add analyzer definitions to Hibernate Search, which can then be referenced from `@Field`. Setting an analysis definition provider does not, in itself, change your mapping in any way.

Comment: That was useful! But... now there is another problem. The file with stop words has few lines, in each line is "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "milk" respectively. The product name is "Shhh Ths Is Not Milk". After index rebuild, I can find my product with "Shhh" only. If I use "milk", none is found which is a confirmation my stop words file is applied. But when I search by "not" or "this" - none is found too. Does it mean my stop words are merged with existing stop words?

Comment: In case it helps: Lucene may not document a feature, but you may find a test class which shows how the feature is used. For example, or the mapping file, used by `MappingCharFilterFactory`, there is [this example](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/d5d6dc079395c47cd6d12dcce3bcfdd2c7d9dc63/lucene/analysis/common/src/test/org/apache/lucene/analysis/custom/mapping1.txt) - where each line has the format `"x" => "y"`.

Comment: You can see how this file is used [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/d5d6dc079395c47cd6d12dcce3bcfdd2c7d9dc63/lucene/analysis/common/src/test/org/apache/lucene/analysis/custom/TestCustomAnalyzer.java#L521) - but that is pure-Lucene not Hibernate. I don't know if Hibernate 5 would handle this for you in the same way, behind the scenes, using `new HashMap<>`

Comment: @horvoje I don't know. Depending on how you build your query, a different analyzer might be applied and remove `not` and `this` from your query. Especially if you don't use Hibernate Search's DSL but use Lucene's `QueryParser` instead. Try calling `toString()` on your query to check that. Otherwise, create a new question with a complete reproducer so that people can try and debug this themselves.